# Better way to fire save auto draft to database base on Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

Can anyone give a better way to fire save_autodraft()? save_autodraft() function will save textarea value into my database base on `Textarea` input throught ajax.

`onchange` seems like a little bit not really efficient way and a little bit costly my server because user usually typing (make changes) every second and typing hundred or thousand characters on it. setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both - throttle the function

```
var timeout;
element.on('input',function() {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       //save
   },1000);
});
```

Comment: What does mean / will happend with this codes? firstly it will detect any changes on element. and inside of it have set time out.

Comment: @KamarulAnuar - it means if a person keeps typing continually then no save event will happen until (in the posted code) 1000ms **after** their last input. Basically, you don't use a setTimeout by itself to call save autodraft, because the user might not have made any changes. So you listen for their changes and then wait until they have stopped for a second. This is an incomplete solution and has drawbacks (e.g. if the user was in the middle of making changes and their laptop died, the last save might've occurred a while ago).

Comment: okay @Adam , I want to try your code. so I need to to put my save_autodaraft() function (ajax on it) behind //save ? save_autodraft();//save ?